# Couldn't Get the Axle Out

Tags: nissan, axle, almera

I wanted to replace the boots on my 99 Almera MTX ( same as the Sentra ) and I got all the way to the point of pulling the axle out of the tranny but I couldn't get it out. I tried to pry it out with a screwdriver like in the Haynes manual, but I bent the screw driver more than once and just couldn't get it out. Also tried rotating the axle a bunch of times [like recommended in one of EricTheCarGuy's vids](https://youtu.be/jydxpsh13WQ?t=6m40s). I did not hit it like he did, I just pushed with constant force to pry like it says in the Haynes manual. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

It says in the Haynes manual:

> Separate the relevant driveshaft from the transmission, using a suitable lever inserted between the casing of the inner constant velocity joint and the transmission casing. Prise out the driveshaft until the retaining circlip compresses into its groove, and is released from the differential sun gear.

Comment: Is it just held in with a spring clip around the splines?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: I wondered that, it looks like someone is saying that you have not made it clear what you are asking.

Comment: @HandyHowie See my edits.

Comment: Striking the joint while prising will probably do it.

Comment: @HandyHowie What joint?  You mean the inner CV joint?  Won't that mess it up?

Comment: No, it won't damage it.  Don't hit it too hard, just shock it with a hammer on its side while prising.

Comment: Don't be gentle with it ... squeeze your buttocks and make it happen.

Answer (score 3):

I know exactly the feeling you are having ... been in this situation many times.

The thing you need to do is be malevolent on it. You need to grab a pry bar which will give you some leverage. Do not be nice to it. Put the pry bar up between the inner CVJ and the case and really have at it. The axle will pop before you hurt anything (besides yourself). Figure out which way to put a pry bar up in there so it will have the greatest effect. It can just be a real pain. Also, you'll want a pan underneath of it because you are sure to lose some transmission oil in the process (after it pops).

While something like this is meant for tearing wood apart, I find the straighter of the two ends (not the hook end) works pretty good in a situation like this:

[image]

It has just enough angle on it to be a good lever without being so bent you cannot get it in there.

Comment: I'll give it a try next time I take a whack at it ( pun intended ) :-)